# How to move pandas column under the last row of the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

I'm trying to manipulate my pandas dataframe so that I can:

1. Create a new column labelled 'Ticker'.
2. Move column 'AAL' below column 'A'
3. Label all elements for column 'A' as A in the new 'Ticker' column and AAL for the newly moved 'AAL' column
4. Rename column 'A' to 'Adj Close'
5. Duplicate index values into the left of column 'Adj Close' for the 'AAL' rows.

Actual Dataframe Output:

```
        Adj Close   Adj Close
        A           AAL
Date            
1/11/19 80.22673035 28.54166412
1/12/19 84.7361908  28.57440376
1/1/20  82.17785645 26.74117851
```

Desired Dataframe Output:

```
        Ticker      Adj Close
Date            
1/11/19    A        80.22673035
1/12/19    A        84.7361908
1/1/20     A        82.17785645     
1/11/19   AAL       28.54166412
1/12/19   AAL       28.57440376
1/1/20    AAL       26.74117851
```

Is this possible and if so what would the best way of doing this be?
I've tried using the groupby function as well as pivot but haven't gotten anywhere with it. I'm new to python so I might be doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help and stay safe :)

EDIT (requested output) `print(df.to_dict())`

```
{('Adj Close', 'A'): 
{Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:00:00'): nan, 
Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'): 80.22673034667969, 
Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'): 84.73619079589844, 
Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 82.1778564453125, 
Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'): 76.71327209472656, 
Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'): 71.28850555419922, 
Timestamp('2020-04-01 00:00:00'): 76.4993667602539, 
Timestamp('2020-05-01 00:00:00'): 87.95530700683594, 
Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'): 88.18482971191406, 
Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'): 96.33000183105469, 
Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'): 100.41999816894531, 
Timestamp('2020-09-01 00:00:00'): 100.94000244140625, 
Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'): 100.01000213623047, 
Timestamp('2020-10-02 00:00:00'): 100.01000213623047}, 
('Adj Close', 'AAL'): 
{Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:00:00'): nan, 
Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'): 28.541664123535156, 
Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'): 28.574403762817383, 
Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 26.741178512573242, 
Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'): 18.9798583984375, 
Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'): 12.1899995803833, 
Timestamp('2020-04-01 00:00:00'): 12.010000228881836, 
Timestamp('2020-05-01 00:00:00'): 10.5, 
Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'): 13.069999694824219, 
Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'): 11.119999885559082, 
Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'): 13.050000190734863, 
Timestamp('2020-09-01 00:00:00'): 12.289999961853027, 
Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'): 13.0, 
Timestamp('2020-10-02 00:00:00'): 13.0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if your column head is multiIndex:

```
df.stack(1).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'Ticker'})
```

Output:

```
      Date Ticker  Adj Close
0  1/11/19      A  80.226730
1  1/11/19    AAL  28.541664
2  1/12/19      A  84.736191
3  1/12/19    AAL  28.574404
4   1/1/20      A  82.177856
5   1/1/20    AAL  26.741179
```

Comment: You too @Scott :-)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I'm getting "IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2", could it be because I haven't duplicated the index values for 'AAL'?

Comment: @YUragun i guess then your dataframe doesn't contains multiindex columns.. Can you show the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: It appears that you must may have a single level column header, we may need to first create the multilevel index using pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays and .str.split.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma MultiIndex([('Adj Close', 'A'), ('Adj Close', 'AAL')], length=2

Comment: @YUrangun... Could you update your question with the output from `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: This actually works. I've just been saving and then reloading the CSV in another module which throws up problems. I'm guessing something changes when it's reloaded back into memory. Thank you both for your help and patience :)